# I am getting frequent randomly crash on java.lang.IllegalStateException on android listview

Tags: android

```
10-10 20:37:19.576: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131296396, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1432)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1119)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:900)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:900)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:900)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1119)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:998)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:918)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6836)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1003)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1640)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4409)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-10 20:37:19.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

Comment: Are you updating the list from another thread?

Comment: i have called efficientAdapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);
  allOrdersList.setAdapter(efficientAdapter);

Comment: and in the rest of the places efficientAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: This exception occurs when the contents of the adapter are changed outside of the UI thread, as it says: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are changing the contents of your adapter from a background thread. Please change your implementation so that you only update your adapter from the UI thread.

The exception itself mentions this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

Here's a good tutorial on proper use of ListViews and adapters:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html